# WPF : derived usercontrol from a control in a different project. How to make it use the same style?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, project, styles, inheritance

I'm using the 'Extended WPF Toolkit' ( http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/ ),
and for my own purposes I've created a generic version of its NumericUpDown control called GNumericUpDown< T > which actually lets me specify what type to use, ie. GNumericUpDown< int >.
(This is done to make sure the control respects the appropriate Min/MaxValues of the wanted type)

To be able to use different types from Xaml, I've created a new project with specific derived versions, f.e. NumericUpDownFloat which is derived from GNumericUpDown< float>.

But when I use the NumericUpDownFloat in XAML, nothing is displayed.
I assume this is because there's only a style specified for the WPF Toolkit's NumericUpDown in the Generic.xaml resourcedictionary of the WPF Toolkit project.

So how can I make all my specific versions (NumericUpDownInt, NumericUpDownByte, ..) actually use *that* style ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the latest source code for the Extended WPF Toolkit. The updated NumericUpDown control allows you to specify what data type to use in the editor. The following code specifies to use an Int32 as the data type instead of the default double. As you can see this is done by setting the ValueType property on the NumericUpDown control.

```
<extToolkit:NumericUpDown Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding Age}" Increment="1" Minimum="18" Maximum="65" ValueType="{x:Type sys:Int32}" />
```

This will eliminate the need for the seperate project with specific dervied controls.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution no longer works in the latest release of the Extended WPF Toolkit (1.5.0) because NumericUpDown is a template.

Comment: If you read the documentation, it states that the NumericUpDown is obsolete and has been replaced with the other data type specific up down controls.

Comment: Exactly. It would be nice if that facility still existed because the toolkit doesn't provide controls for every numeric type, such as UInt32.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you make any type of custom control, WPF puts this in the static contructor of the class for you:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
```

This tells WPF that you are going to supply a theme for it somehow.  By default, a Themes folder will be created at the root of the project, with a Generic.xaml file created with the CustomControl1 style and control template put inside of it.

If you want to tell WPF you will be override the style (or really, overriding the default style key dependency property), you just put that line in you static constructor.  If you want it to fall back to whatever it's parent style is, you just omit that line and something like this:

```
public class SuperAwesomeControl : Border
{
    ....
}
```

Will always look like border by default.